# Password protect the boot menu on a desktop computer

Tags: security, boot, passwords

On most computers we can press a key, in my case F12, to access the boot menu where we can choose to boot from another drive, such as the CD or another HD.

I want to eliminate that possibility or ask to be asked a password when I tried to boot a computer that way.

I do not want the computer to ask a password when it boots normally to Windows, but only if someone tries to access the boot menu.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try assigning a BIOS / administration password as the boot menu may be covered by that, however, if this doesn't work and you do not want a boot password, I do not think there will be any way to achieve what you want.

Comment: BIOS admin password or nothing... ;) Sorry

Comment: If you set a BIOS password and that doesn't protect the boot menu, you can normally set the boot order to only allow your main hard drive. This is of course dependent on the motherboard and what options are allowed. This would only protect against idle attempts to boot alternate media. If the computer is stolen, this measure is easily defeated. All you have to do is use the reset CMOS jumper or remove the battery. Something that take 10 seconds once you gain access to the inside of the machine.

Comment: No matter the boot order I choose on the BIOS, that can easily be circumvented by pressing F12 right after POST.

Comment: @Doltknuckle, @elvispt, as I said, this would be the only way to do it - If the BIOS doesn't support password protecting it, you are out of luck.... Unless you want to download a BIOS update and hex edit it to get rid of the boot menu all together.... but I wouldn't recommend it!

Comment: Set the BIOS setup password, then DISABLE all but your main hard drive as boot options in the BIOS.  Don't just change the order, you need to disable/remove the other options.  Your BIOS should then prompt for a password if one of the removed options is chosen from the boot menu.

Comment: @pipTheGeek, that is pretty much what I wrote - but again, as I said, password on boot menu is BIOS dependent.

Comment: I'm accepting Wil's answer. Not being albe to do it, is also an anwswer. A correct one in this case.
Thanks folks. :)

Answer (score 4):

But Bios password doesn't improve security much. If you need to protect your hard drive from access from another Os only secure option is disk encryption (for full security it should be combined with TPM),

Comment: i'm not sure that's his goal, but you're right about the security picture here.

Comment: Indeed it's not my goal. If I wanted total security I would just put a password so that nobody would access the computer, but I just want to prevent access to the boot menu or password protect it.

Comment: Encrypting the hard disk without also protecting the BIOS doesn't work.  A recently-published exploit shows that an attacker can install a keylogger even if they can't decrypt the hard drive.  The keylogger then steals the password for the drive.  It's the "Evil Maid" exploit if you want to search for it.

Comment: BIOS password wouldn't protect against it. Attacker can remove hard drive and install key logger. Please read Joana's Rutkowska article again. Only "good enough" protection against that attack is TPM (it's not 100% bullet prof but TPM hacking required expensive laboratory hardware).

Answer (score 1):

On one of my machines, the BIOS boot password is not effective until I change TWO settings:

```
1. Set an administrator password
2. Set something like "BIOS changes require Password" to "Boot requires Password"
```

Sorry for not having the correct wording, I am not in front of the BIOS (obviously). This accomplishes BIOS
Then F12 or other buttons do not work any more. Of course the bios-reset jumper still applies...

Answer (score 0):

Windows bootloader does not support password protection at all. You'll have to install [GRUB bootloader](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) in order to have this feature.

Comment: Wouldn't accomplish what I'm after. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect the system from attackers, physical security is your best bet.  Put a physical lock on the case like the old IBM systems, and the attacker would have to open the system and switch cables to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Very low tech, not ideal, circumventable, but possibly very effective for a typical user and most applications:  Physically render the F12 key on the keyboard non-functional.  Pop open the keyboard and sever the connection that key has or otherwise interfere with the contact while allowing normal motion.  F12 isn't exactly a commonly used key.

Comment: what an ugly hack...  i like it.  it might do the trick.  but getting around it is just as low-tech: plug in a different (non-hacked) keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

simply put, this cannot be done.

unless, of course, you find a BIOS editor compatible with your BIOS and brace yourself for the chance of bricking it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. The only reason I know this is because I just purchased a used computer. The woman who had this computer knew her stuff. I am using a guest account currently on the computer. Her boot, bios, and command prompt settings are locked down. I can access command prompt in safe mode and monitor the majority of the profile information. However, if I attempt to change anything it just tells me denied. I have two programs that can get around her passwords but one will have to access the boot menu to load. This will not work. the only other option I have is to force her bios password with another program, if I can get that to work even. This woman went through a lot of trouble just to protect this computer.

Comment: Assuming you're getting in touch with the previous owner to fix this, please edit your post to explain what the previous owner did. In its current state this post is not an answer, and should have been a comment. Thanks.